# Creating supervisor process groups across multiple configuration files?

Tags: supervisord

Is it possible to add supervisor programs to the same group even if they're in different files?

I have two configuration files:

process1.conf:

```
[program:process1]
blah

[group:commongroup]
programs:process1
```

process2.conf:

```
[program:process2]
blah

[group:commongroup]
programs:process2
```

However, when I load this into supervisor, it creates the daemons:

```
process1:process1
process2:process2
commongroup:process2
```

When I would have expected:

```
commongroup:process1
commongroup:process2
```

Why is it creating groups named "process1" and "process2" when I don't specify those group names? And why is it only adding one program to "commongroup" when both conf files specify it?

My goal is to keep configurations in separate files for ease of maintenance, but kept the actual running daemons organized under a common group for ease of administration (e.g. so I can do `sudo supervisor stop commongroup:*`)

Answer (score 3):

It's possible have a dedicated config file for definition of group only.

process1.conf:

```
[program:process1]
blah
```

process2.conf:

```
[program:process2]
blah
```

000-commongroup.conf

```
[group:commongroup]
programs:process1,process2
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to add multiple programs to the same group by separating them with "**,**" . In the current case, removing one of the groups from one of the files and adding the program name to the group does have them under common group.
Having process1 as

```
[program:process1]
blah
```

and process2.conf as

```
[program:process2]
blah

[group:commongroup]
programs:process2,process1
```

does group them under single prefix, to start and stop together.

And the process names across multiple **.conf** files must be unique for supervisor to behave as expected.